# CSS or jQuery Selector for span within span

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I am trying to select a span within a span within a div using plain CSS or JQuery selectors. The html is as follows:

```
<div id="example2_paginate" class="dataTables_paginate paging_full_numbers">
<span id="example2_first" class="first paginate_button paginate_button_disabled">First</span>
<span id="example2_previous" class="previous paginate_button paginate_button_disabled">Previous</span>
<span>
<span class="paginate_active">1</span>
<span class="paginate_button">2</span>
<span class="paginate_button">3</span>
<span class="paginate_button">4</span>
<span class="paginate_button">5</span>
</span>
<span id="example2_next" class="next paginate_button">Next</span>
<span id="example2_last" class="last paginate_button">Last</span>
</div>
```

I want to select spans that contain 1 to 5 (paginate_active and the 5 paginate buttons), **individually.**

With my very limited knowledge of CSS and jQuery I've tried a couple of things but I'm sure my syntax is wrong, like `$("paging_full_numbers span:eq(1)")` .

Could you please give me a hint of how to go about it?

Comment: Is it *valid* (per-specification) for a SPAN to be nested inside a SPAN?

Comment: I am not sure about that, but that could is coming from a jQuery plugin (datatables) and (even though I can) I don't want to change the source code that generates it as I want to maintain compatibility with future versions.

Comment: had a quick google, yes, it is valid for SPANs to contain inline elements such as SPANs.

Comment: @pst: Sure it is. I can't think of any reason why not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select them individually, you can simply select them all and then use jQuerys `.each()`. For example

`spanList = $('#example2_paginate').find('.paginate_active, .paginate_button');`

will find all classes of 'paginate_active' or 'paginate_button' that, are inside your element of id=example2_paginate. Then you can write:

```
 spanList.each(function(index){
    <-- code here for occurence of index index-->
});
```

Alternatively to select the i^th button without looping through them all:

```
spanList.eq(i)
```

See jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t4KWr/

Comment: thanks. Isn't there a way of directly selecting an element (say span with '3' above) without having to put it into a variable / loop?

Comment: Yeah, spanList.eq(3) should do it - you can use it even without the 'each' function. The 'each' function is just handy if you are wanting to do something to each occurrence in turn.

Comment: strabge, it doesn't seem to be able to find those - I've tried a few other things, even a simple $(".paginate_active") doesn't return anything! Must be something to do with DOM parser not liking nested spans, or else me being a javascript newbie! :)

Comment: If I do this: $("span").css("border","3px solid red"); then it will only put borders on the outer span around 1-5, it does not border them individually. In other words it doesn't consider them as spans?!

Comment: also this doesn't find the inner spans: $("body").find("span").css("border","3px solid red");

Comment: Not sure what's gone wrong there without seeing the code - but it should find them all.

Comment: I've just tested, $("body").find("span").css("border","3px solid red"); and it found them all fine. I think the problem is elsewhere, but I can't be sure without seeing your code. Edit your question to include the jQuery?

Comment: Ashkan - I missed a comma after '.paginate_active'. But the code you've tested above should work.

Answer (score 1):

This CSS is what you want.

```
div.paging_full_numbers > span > span.paginate_active, div.paging_full_numbers > span > span.paginate_button
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to get, say, the third of the 5 spans would be:

```
$(".paging_full_numbers > span > span:nth-child(3)")
```

Comment: thanks this doesn't seem to work either, seem my comments on @Stephen Harris answer above - seems to be a problem with nested spans?

Comment: yep works here too: http://jsfiddle.net/uDRhr/5/ but doesn't work on the actual page / browser!

Comment: I forgot to mention that html snippet above is inside a few other elements (div, tbody etc) within the page but it shouldn't make any difference, my example should still work!

Answer (score 0):

its seem that there is a problem with

```
$("paging_full_numbers span:eq(1)")
```

You should write like

```
$("#paging_full_numbers span:eq(1)")
```

Or if you are using class

```
 $(".paging_full_numbers span:eq(1)")
```

Answer (score 0):

This select spans that contain 1 to 5 (paginate_active and the 5 paginate buttons), individually:

```
$("div.paging_full_numbers span:[class='paginate_active'],[class='paginate_button']").each(function(){
    //do what you want here
});
```

That select the span's with only class 'paginate_active' or only class 'paginate_button'

Comment: yep, tried, didn't work, please check comments on answers from Stephen Harris and peirix

Comment: But you wanted change, in this case css style, in all the span's? Or only those than have only the class 'paginate_active' or 'paginate_button'?
Because what i said above was exactly what you want (select spans that contain 1 to 5 (paginate_active and the 5 paginate buttons), individually).

Comment: I wanted access to only paginate_* spans, you are correct. The code example I gave (with css borders) was to illustrate the problem. Oddly enough it works fine on jsFiddle etc but not in browser.